How can I assign a shortcut in Karabiner-Elements to open VS Code?
I am new to Karabiner-Elements and I am trying to find a way to assign a shortcut to open VS Code.
I would like to press Left Command and Right Command at the same time then leave it then press V to open VS Code in Karabiner-Element.
